# My Internet Connection Randomly Drops Off

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've been facing this problem for a while now, and no solution can solve this. My internet randomly drops off.

- It's very irregular, really. There are times when it stays days without dropping and there are days that drops every single hour.
- When i reboot the router, most of the times the internet gets back.
- There are 3 computers in my house, two windows 7 and one MAC Mavericks... When it drops, it drops in all of them, including the one connected to the router.
- I can't complete any download of bigger files (like, more than 50mb). "The network connection was lost" error appears in every browser (Chrome, Safari, IE and Firefox), even if the internet didn't even dropped.
- Sometimes, when the phone rings, the internet drops instantly. But not every time, and sometimes it drops without the phone ringing.

Help, please!

Comment: Did you call your ISP?

Comment: sounds like either the wrong profile (call isp) or you have the broadband filter in the wrong place, or not on. the adsl filter needs to be the absolute first thing in the Telephone socket, and if you have more than one phone in the house you need to have a filter on every socket a phone or device is in.